# Prometheus HA setup with InfluxDB backend

Tags: prometheus

I'm running Prometheus HA setup according to [official FAQ](https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/faq/#can-prometheus-be-made-highly-available) (two prometheus instances scraping the same data) and would like to use InfluxDB as a [remote storage backend](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/#remote-storage-integrations).

Should I be worried about having duplicate data points in the database? Is there something I can use to deduplicate the data being writtent to InfluxDB?

Comment: Facing similar situation here. Currently having each prometheus server write to its own InluxDB instance as clustering is enterprise only option now. But, not sure if this is the best way.